# Hide container div below menu bar div using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fixed header and menu bar and there is a container div when i scroll down the container div does not hide itself below the menu bar as shown in image below is the jquery code i am using. Please help to solve my issue.

```
var header= $('.header');
var start_div = $(header).offset().top;


var menu_div = $('.menu');
var menu = $(menu_div ).offset().top;

  $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
        var p = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(header).css('position',((p)>start_div ) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
        $(header).css('top',((p)>start_div ) ? '0px' : '');
        $(header).css('width','840px');
        $(header).css('min-height','108px');

 });

$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
   var p = $(window).scrollTop()+100;
   $(menu_div).css('position',((p)>menu) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
   $(menu_div).css('top',((p)>menu) ? '110px' : '');
   $(menu_div).css('width','575px');
   $(menu_div).css('height','57px');
 });
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your html. Also, why are you using jquery for this? I might be missing something, but the effect is achievable with only html+css

Comment: because i want to fix header and menu items when user scrolls to a particular point but i want to hide the white container as soon as it goes under the menu item

Comment: Check my answer. Setting `position: fixed` and `background-color: white;` in the header container achieves exactly that without any JS

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something you don't need jQuery or even JS to do that.

Check the snippet ([**codePen here**](http://codepen.io/tivie/pen/XbqNvp))

```css
html, 
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.header-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: white;
}

.header {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 170px; /* same as height of header + nav + margins + 10px for coolness*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header">Blue Header</div>
    <div class="menu">Green Menu</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    My content<br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    blabla
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    blabla
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the css z-index property.

```
.header, .menu { 
    z-index: 2
} 
.container {
    z-index: 1
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp